# Regex is not working as expected in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB as a database. And for some use cases, I need to search by email address. So the user will enter some text (maybe a complete or incomplete email address), and then I need to filter the document. I am using regex for filtering.

```js
if (search) {
    regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
}
```

And query looks like this

```
query: {
       ...(search && {
           $or: [
               { 'user.firstName': regex },
               { 'user.lastName': regex },
               { 'user.email': regex },
           ],
       }),
   }
```

But it is not fetching anything. Even I tried it using MongoDB Compass but it didn't work.
You can see prashant.singh+07/04@testunity.com exists in the DB.

[image]

But when I write the same as the search query it didn't work

```
{"project._id" : ObjectId('6438ccea78ceb75cf48fced8'), "user.email" : {$regex : 'prashant.singh+07/04@testunity.com', $options : "i"}}
```

It results in nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regex pattern is invalid and contains symbols with special meanings in Regex.

Paste your regex pattern in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and you will find that it is invalid because it contains unescaped `\` character.

While these symbols have special meanings in Regex:

`.` - Match any character

`+` - Match previous token with one or unlimited times

In order to fix your regex, you should escape these characters with a `\` (backslash).

```
prashant\.singh\+07\/04@testunity\.com
```

[Demo @ Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/mEZ2Jk/1)

While in JS wise, make sure that the input is escaped for the Regex characters before filtering via the function below:

```js
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"); // $& means the whole matched string
}
```

```js
if (search) {
    regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), 'i');
}
```

Reference: [Escaping (section) Regular expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions#escaping)